# help with differential equation using substitution

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, substitution

I have the following differential equation:
$$xe^xy'-\dfrac{y}{x}e^x+x\cos (x)=0$$

I tried using substitution, namely:

Let $v=\dfrac{y}{x}$, then $\dfrac{dy}{dx}=\dfrac{dv}{dx}x+v$. Substituting yields:

$$xe^x\left(\dfrac{dv}{dx}x+v\right)-ve^x+x\cos (x)=\dfrac{dv}{dx}x+v-\dfrac{v}{x}+e^{-x}\cos (x)=0$$

But it is still not separable. I also tried the substitution $v=\dfrac{y}{x^2}$. That didn't work either.

For this problem, a substitution should work; honestly, I think I am making a stupid mistake and that's why I am stuck. Could anyone shed me some light on this equation?

Comment: How about $v=e^{-1/x}y$?

That way you have $xe^{x-1/x}v'+(1/x)e^{x-1/x}v-(1/x)e^{x-1/x}v=xe^{x-1/x}v'$

Thus you would just have to solve $xe^{x-1/x}v'=-xcos(x)$

And by integrating on both sides and clearing the natural logarithm you have the answer.

Comment: Nice! How did you see it? I was thinking for a while and that didn't occur to me. I thought of $v=ye^x$, but that doesn't work.

Comment: This is a first order linear ODE. Integrating factor is the most straightforward method.

Comment: by integrating i.e: $xe^xy'-\dfrac{e^x}{x}y$, then f(x)=g(x)h(x) thus f'(x)=g'(x)h(x)+g(x)h'(x) , by taking h(x)=e^x*y(x) then I know that g'(x)=$\dfrac{1}{x^2}$g(x) => g(x)=e^(-1/x)

Answer (score 1):

I would start by noticing that

\begin{align*}
xe^{x}y' - \frac{y}{x}e^{x} + x\cos(x) = 0 & \Longleftrightarrow y' - \frac{y}{x^{2}} + e^{-x}\cos(x) = 0\\\\
& \Longleftrightarrow e^{1/x}y' - \frac{e^{1/x}}{x^{2}}y = -e^{-x + 1/x}\cos(x)\\\\
& \Longleftrightarrow (ye^{1/x})' = -e^{-x + 1/x}\cos(x)
\end{align*}

Apparently, this is as far as one can go.

Hopefully this helps!

Comment: It does help. But yeah, I am not sure how to go forward. At this point I can just try to guess some particular solution, although the problem asked for a general solution.